# Django: Permissions based on Model Instance

Tags: django, django-models, permissions, django-permissions

I have a model `class Project` and for each model instance, there should be a 'group' of users who may edit that instance. I guess I could add another model class called ProjectEditor to add those editors. Is there a better way of implementing this? What about checking for permissions? I would need to write my own permission method then too, right?

Thanks
Eric

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Model* (table) level permissions can be achieved using the [groups](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/topics/auth/#groups) facility provided by Django `auth`. Groups let you create custom permissions at a *model* level. *Instance* (row) level would be trickier. You would most likely have to write a custom mechanism to accomplish this.

Here is a [Django Snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1054/) that might give you some ideas.

Answer (score 15):

[Django Guardian](https://github.com/lukaszb/django-guardian) seems to be the best solution today for Model instance level permissions.

Answer (score 2):

There was an open source release for row/object level permissions by the washington times team that might be of use:

- [Django Object Permissions Proof of Concept](http://opensource.washingtontimes.com/blog/post/coordt/2009/12/django-object-permissions-proof-concept/)

Comment: @DanAbramov: Try http://code.osuosl.org/projects/object-permissions where you can find the 1.3.1 release from March.